# Text manipulation within a dataframe: words extraction

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to check the word next to a number. 
For example, I have this column in my dataframe: 
    Recipes

```
Halve the clementine and place into the cavity along with the bay leaves. Transfer the duck to a medium roasting tray and roast for around 1 hour 20 minutes.
Add the stock, then bring to the boil and reduce to a simmer for around 15 minutes.
2 heaped teaspoons Chinese five-spice 
100 ml Marsala
1 litre organic chicken stock
```

I would like to get a new column where I extract them:

```
New Column
[1 hour, 20 minutes]
15 minutes
2 heaped
100 ml
1 litre
```

as I need to compare to a list of values:

```
to_compare= ["1 hour", "20 litres", "100 ml", "2", "15 minutes", "20 minutes"]
```

to see how many elements per each row are in common. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `Series.str.extractall` with the pattern `numbers - space - letter`. Then we check which matches are in `to_compare`, and finally we use `GroupBy.sum` to get how many matches we have

```
matches = df['Col'].str.extractall('(\d+\s\w+)')
df['matches'] = matches[0].isin(to_compare).groupby(level=0).sum()

                                                 Col  matches
0  Halve the clementine and place into the cavity...      2.0
1  Add the stock, then bring to the boil and redu...      1.0
2              2 heaped teaspoons Chinese five-spice      0.0
3                                     100 ml Marsala      1.0
4                      1 litre organic chicken stock      0.0
```

Also, `matches` returns:

```
                  0
  match            
0 0          1 hour
  1      20 minutes
1 0      15 minutes
2 0        2 heaped
3 0          100 ml
4 0         1 litre
```

To get these in a list, use:

```
matches.groupby(level=0).agg(list)

                      0
0  [1 hour, 20 minutes]
1          [15 minutes]
2            [2 heaped]
3              [100 ml]
4             [1 litre]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to build the pattern that can extract the number and the following word, then apply this function to the whole column of your dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Halve the clementine and place into the cavity along with the bay leaves. Transfer the duck to a medium roasting tray and roast for around 1 hour 20 minutes.",
           "Add the stock, then bring to the boil and reduce to a simmer for around 15 minutes.",
           "2 heaped teaspoons Chinese five-spice",
           "100 ml Marsala",
           "1 litre organic chicken stock"]})


def extract_qty(txt):
  return re.findall('\d+ \w+',txt)

df['extracted_qty'] = df['text'].apply(extract_qty)

df    
#   text                                                extracted_qty
#0  Halve the clementine and place into the cavity...   [1 hour, 20 minutes]
#1  Add the stock, then bring to the boil and redu...   [15 minutes]
#2  2 heaped teaspoons Chinese five-spice               [2 heaped]
#3  100 ml Marsala                                      [100 ml]
#4  1 litre organic chicken stock                       [1 litre]
```

Extract common values with `to_compare` and a list comprehension:

```
to_compare= ["1 hour", "20 litres", "100 ml", "2", "15 minutes", "20 minutes"]

df['common'] = df['extracted_qty'].apply(lambda x: [el for el in x if el in to_compare])


#   text                        extracted_qty           common
#0  Halve the clementine ...    [1 hour, 20 minutes]    [1 hour, 20 minutes]
#1  Add the stock, then  ...    [15 minutes]            [15 minutes]
#2  2 heaped teaspoons ...      [2 heaped]              []
#3  100 ml Marsala              [100 ml]                [100 ml]
#4  1 litre organic chicken...  [1 litre]               []
```